# Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.time.LocalDateTime cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, liquibase

While integrating liquibase in spring boot. Getting issue with bean creation.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-04-12 13:50:58.199 ERROR 28283 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.time.LocalDateTime cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at com.demo.liquidemo.LiquidemoApplication.main(LiquidemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.time.LocalDateTime cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at liquibase.changelog.StandardChangeLogHistoryService.getRanChangeSets(StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java:328) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.AbstractChangeLogHistoryService.upgradeChecksums(AbstractChangeLogHistoryService.java:66) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.StandardChangeLogHistoryService.upgradeChecksums(StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java:297) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.checkLiquibaseTables(Liquibase.java:1174) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:178) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:368) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:316) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Comment: The error is actually self explanatory. I can't say much more, since you haven't shown any code

Comment: Also, you may be using spring, spring-boot and all that, but that doesn't mean it is relevant to the issue at hand

Comment: @Stultuske However Liquibase is relevant (as the exception occurs inside Liquibase), so it is not clear to me why you removed that tag as well. I have added it back.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known problem in liquibase and mysql-connector. Discussed in their GitHub https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1639. Looks like it was fixed in latest versions.